# Unable to execute python script directly

Tags: bash, python

I have [a python script (`peepdf.py`)](http://eternal-todo.com/tools/peepdf-pdf-analysis-tool) that I would like to execute directly by simple typing it in terminal then pass it the parameters it expects. To do this, I moved the folder which contains the script and other dependencies to `/usr/local/bin` directory then added to that full path to the `~/.bashrc` file so that it becomes persistent.

Nonetheless, now when I type the command in terminal, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

So I checked and I do have python installed since I went to the directory `/usr/bin` and saw it there `python3` and `python2.7`, etc.

The only way I am able to run my script is by typing:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/peepdf_0.3/peepdf.py -i test.pdf
```

Any way to make this script more accessible in terms of writing?

Update: Here is the line added to the .bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/peepdf_0.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise against changing the `PATH` variable for just a single script. If you're not going to use it in any other environment, you can simply change your script's shebang to point to `python2.7` directly:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

This way you can execute it with the full path, e.g.:

```bsh
/usr/local/bin/peepdf_0.3/peepdf.py -i test.pdf
```

If you however want to execute it conveniently with just a single keyword, I'd define an `alias` in the `~/.bash_aliases` file, let's take “peepdf”:

```bsh
alias peepdf='/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/peepdf_0.3/peepdf.py'
```

With that you're able to run your script simply with e.g.:

```bsh
peepdf -i test.pdf
```